# python regular expression grouping

Tags: python, regex

My regular expression goal:

"If the sentence has a '#' in it,  group all the stuff to the left of the '#' and group all the stuff to the right of the '#'.  If the character doesn't have a '#', then just return the entire sentence as one group"

Examples of the two cases:

```
A) '120x4#Words' -> ('120x4', 'Words')
B) '120x4@9.5' -> ('120x4@9.5')
```

I made a regular expression that parses case A correctly

```
(.*)(?:#(.*))

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'120x4', u'words')
```

But of course this won't work for case B -- I need to make "# and everything to the right of it" optional

So I tried to use the '?' "zero or none" operator on that second grouping to indicate it's optional.
`(.*)(?:#(.*))?`

But it gives me bad results.  The first grouping eats up the entire string.

```
# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'120x4#words', None)
```

Guess I'm either misunderstanding the none-or-one '?' operator and how it works on groupings or I am misunderstanding how the first group is acting greedy and grabbing the entire string.  I did try to make the first group 'reluctant', but that gave me a total no-match.

```
(.*?)(?:#(.*))?


# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*?)#(.*)|(.+)
```

this sjould work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/14

Comment: Wow, and that's a great site to test regular expressions too -- thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the standard [`str.split`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/stdtypes#str.split) function:

```
s = '120x4#Words'
x = s.split( '#' )
```

If you still want a regex solution, use the following pattern:

```
([^#]+)(?:#(.*))?
```

Comment: +1 for `str.split`, though the regex is only equivalent for up 1 occurence of `#` in the string...

Answer (score 1):

use `re.split`  :

```
>>> import re
>>> a='120x4#Words'
>>> re.split('#',a)
['120x4', 'Words']
>>> b='120x4@9.5'
>>> re.split('#',b)
['120x4@9.5']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose `re` solution. But, you're better off using `str.split`.

```
import re

REGEX = re.compile(r'''
    \A
    (?P<left>.*?)
    (?:
        [#]
        (?P<right>.*)
    )?
    \Z
''', re.VERBOSE)


def parse(text):
    match = REGEX.match(text)
    if match:
        return tuple(filter(None, match.groups()))

print(parse('120x4#Words'))
print(parse('120x4@9.5'))
```

**Better solution**

```
def parse(text):
    return text.split('#', maxsplit=1)

print(parse('120x4#Words'))
print(parse('120x4@9.5'))
```

Comment: yeah, agree the split is tidier.  Just tonight I'm experimenting with regular expressions...  the VERBOSE modifier looks like it can save me some debugging headache in the future....